# Biblatex create a \citejournal command with journaltitle, date, title

Tags: macros, biblatex, citing

Hello latex community!

I'm trying to set a specific command to cite journal articles which doesn't show the author but the journal title, the date and then the article title.

I've found this answer: [How to create a \citejournal, \citebooktitle, \cite... command in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26682/how-to-create-a-citejournal-citebooktitle-cite-command-in-biblatex)

My problem is that it doesn't not provide the date nor the article title so I've modified it a bit:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{journal}
     \usebibmacro{date}
       \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

It's now almost perfect as I see the journal and the article title but the date does not show.

Here is a short MWE with the citation I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
      {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{journal}
         \usebibmacro{date}
           \usebibmacro{title}}
      {\multicitedelim}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author = {Author, A.},
  date = {2011-06-12},
  title = {Some relevant article},
  journal = {Test journal}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

Some text~\citejournal{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are seeing that the `date` bibmacro is being cleared, so there is nothing to print.  This is a result of your using the `authoryear` style for `biblatex`.  The [example document](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/50-style-authoryear.pdf) for the `authoryear` style gives a bit more detail:

> Since this style prints the date label after the author/editor in the bibliography,
>   there are effectively two dates in the bibliography: the full date specification
>   (e.g., “2001”, “June 2006”, “5th Jan. 2008”) and the date label (e.g., “2006a”),
>   as found in citations. The mergedate option controls whether or not date
>   specifications are merged with the date label.

So, when the style works to merge the two fields together, it dispenses with the `date` bibmacro and "disables" it to avoid any issues.

Your options are to:

1. Add `mergedata=false` to prevent the style from merging the dates, which will keep the `date` bibmacro intact, but also (possibly) affect the presentation of items in the bibliography.
2. Recreate the bibmacro with `\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdate}` - this is the original definition of the macro.
3. Switch to using `\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}` in the citation command.  This is the "newer" bibmacro that the style defines to make the date label that appears right after the author in the bibliography.
4. Use a different style that doesn't have these peculiarities.

---

In any event, you may wish to adjust your delimiter between the fields, depending on what you desire.  The example below exercises option 3 above and simply inserts space between each unit.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
      {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{journal}
        \setunit{\addspace} % space delimiter
        \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}
        \setunit{\addspace} % space delimiter
           \usebibmacro{title}}
      {\multicitedelim}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Result:

[image: bib]

Comment: +1 Though the command should probably be called `\citearticle` now, as it does not only print the `journal`.

Comment: Thx I've decided to go for the option 2 as I need to print the full date in the citation for the demonstration.

What is very surprising is that I am actually using biblatex with authortitle-icomp as a citestyle and authoryear as a bibstyle... when I supress the bibstyle it prints the date in the citation and the bibliography whereas when I had it the date disappear in both. Anyway with solution it works perfectly thanks!