# two different citation styles for same bibliography

Tags: bibtex, citing, acm, paper, acmart

I have very little experience with latex and my task is to write a report in the [ACM article template](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). The bibliography style is numbered:

```
[1] Some Author, some title, ...
```

Where

```
Some text\cite{author:title}.
```

results in:

```
Some text[1].
```

I would like to be able to produce the following:

```
[Author, year] propose an algorithm to... Bla bla bla [1].
```

In other words, use both the acm citation style and the author-year style on the same bibliography. Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there maybe another convention to write about the author of a paper? I wouldn't like to type the author's name explicitly, like this:

```
Some Author propose an algorithm...
```

But rather use some command (maybe I have to define one? I don't know how):

```
\magiccite{author:title} propose an algorithm to... Bla bla bla \cite{autor:title}.
```

Thank you and sorry for my inexperience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about some special cite commands. In my case

```
\citeauthor
```

does the job. Took the answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26682/how-to-create-a-citejournal-citebooktitle-cite-command-in-biblatex). I am a beginner, sorry again.